# TypeScript - Nested map type design

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, alias

I have a situation where i need to create a new type **A** that could be a class/constructor type OR a MapType. The MapType contains two types: a type for the key and a type for the value. These two types are of type **A**, because it is also possible to have nested maps.

This is my class/constructor type:

```
export type Clazz<T> = { new(...args: any[]): T };
```

Do you have any suggestion on how to design it?

**--- Update ---**

I was thinking of something like this:

```
export type Type<T = any> = ClassType<T> | MapType;

export type ClassType<T> = { new(...args: any[]): T };

export interface MapType { key: Type, value: Type };
```

I need class constructors to instantiate them later.
What if I wanted generics for MapType? Any suggestion?

Comment: This is an interesting question. Unfortunately I'm having a bit of trouble trying to understand what you're trying to do and you're diving a bit in to ["XY Problem"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) territory. Could you add more context?

Comment: Also, in javascript/typescript, for objects, the key can only be of type `string | number`. So the "a type for the key" may not make sense. Could you clarify?

Comment: `type A = {key: A, value: A} | Clazz<any>`?  If `A` is a class constructor, what type does it construct?  (That is, what should be in place of `any`?)

Comment: @RicoKahler i need a type for the key, because i'm building a serializer/deserializer that can take the value of the key (string), and, according to the declared type, instantiate the corresponding class using the correct parser.

Comment: @jcalz a generic type T. So this is the problem, because i don't know how to write the map type after that.

Comment: I think you need to include examples of values that do and do not fit the type you're looking for.  Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: Remember that types don't actually exist at run-time (though class constructors do, of course). You may be better off using some sort of [descriminator](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/discriminated-unions.html) as a key rather than a type.